# What CVS client for Java do you recommend?

Tags: java, cvs

I'm looking for a CVS client to embed in my Java application. What do you recommend?

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend CVS at all so I’m out. :)

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah, I know... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [JavaCVS](http://javacvs.netbeans.org/library/).  Oh yeah, and to repeat what dozens of people will undoubtably add to this question, if it is at all possible to use SVN instead of CVS in your system, do it.